# Pascal's Triangle Generator in Python

Tags: python

So I've been working on a generator for Pascal's triangle in Python. Now, I wouldn't call myself a Python god, so my program is a lot longer than the very confusing ones on the internet. It's more of a logical approach to creating the triangle.

Here's the program:

```
def double_chunker(lst):
  leng = len(lst)
  for i in range(leng):
    if i == 0:
      yield [lst[0]]
    elif i == 1:
      yield [lst[0], lst[1]]
    elif i == leng:
      yield [lst[-1]]
    else:
      yield [lst[i-1], lst[i]]
  yield [lst[-1]]

def chunk_adder(lst):
  for i in lst:
    if len(i) == 1:
      yield i[0]
    else:
      yield sum(i)

def pascal_next(lst):
  return list(chunk_adder(double_chunker(lst)))

def pascal_triangle(rows):
  end = [[1]]
  for i in range(rows):
    end.append(pascal_next(end[-1]))
  return end
```

A simple go-through of how it works:

1. `double_chunker()` splits up a row of Pascal's triangle into the pairs of numbers you would use when adding up to determine the numbers in the next row. This algorithm is little *jerry-rigged* - I had to add some special exceptions for some numbers on the end of the row to make it work properly.
2. `chunk_adder()` adds together a list of chunks generated by `double_chunker` to determine the next row in the Pascal sequence.
3. `pascal_next()`combines both `double_chunker()` and `chunk_adder()` to, when given one row in Pascal's triangle, determine the next row in the triangle.
4. `pascal_triangle()` iteratively creates rows of Pascal's triangle using `pascal_next()`.

So, here are some of my questions:

1. Is there anything in my program that seems redundant, repetitive, or can be shortened?
2. Is there any better code practices I should be employing and am not?

And obviously, as always, feel free to provide any other feedback you may have. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> def chunk_adder(lst):
>   for i in lst:
>     if len(i) == 1:
>       yield i[0]
>     else:
>       yield sum(i)
> ```

`sum` can happilly consume iterable of size 1, it can even consume iterable of size 0:

```
>>> sum([1])
1
>>> sum([])
0
```

So you can simplify it to:

```
def chunck_adder(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        yield sum(element)
```

Which is simply

```
def chunck_adder(iterable):
    yield from map(sum, iterable)
```

So you could simplify `pascal_next` instead:

```
def pascal_next(lst):
    return list(map(sum, double_chunker(lst)))
```

---

> ```
> def double_chunker(lst):
>   leng = len(lst)
>   for i in range(leng):
>     if i == 0:
>       yield [lst[0]]
>     elif i == 1:
>       yield [lst[0], lst[1]]
>     elif i == leng:
>       yield [lst[-1]]
>     else:
>       yield [lst[i-1], lst[i]]
>   yield [lst[-1]]
> ```

The intent is pretty much the same than the [`pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from `itertools`. Except you want to yield the first and last element as well.

Here you have two possibilities:

- either yield them manually:

  ```
  import itertools

  def double_chunker(lst):
      if not lst:
          return
      a, b = itertools.tee(lst)
      next(b, None)

      yield [lst[0]]
      yield from zip(a, b)
      yield [lst[-1]]
  ```

  But this forces the argument to be a list, or at least to know if its empty and to implement `__getitem__`.
- or add boundary values to your input so `pairwise` can work properly:

  ```
  import itertools


  def pairwise(iterable):
      a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
      next(b, None)
      return zip(a, b)


  def double_chuncker(iterable):
      extended = itertools.chain([0], iterable, [0])
      return pairwise(extended)
  ```

  Which I recommend because it happily consume any iterable.

---

> ```
> def pascal_triangle(rows):
>   end = [[1]]
>   for i in range(rows):
>     end.append(pascal_next(end[-1]))
>   return end
> ```

Instead of relying on the list being constructed, I would explicitly store the current row. I would also turn this into an infinite generator because it really is and maybe provide an helper function for convenience:

```
def pascal_triangle():
    row = [1]
    while True:
        yield row
        row = pascal_next(row)


def pascal_triangle_up_to(n):
    return list(itertools.islice(pascal_triangle(), n))
```

---

Full code:

```
import itertools


def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def double_chuncker(iterable):
    extended = itertools.chain([0], iterable, [0])
    return pairwise(extended)


def pascal_next(iterable):
    return list(map(sum, double_chuncker(iterable)))


def pascal_triangle():
    row = [1]
    while True:
        yield row
        row = pascal_next(row)


def pascal_triangle_up_to(n):
    return list(itertools.islice(pascal_triangle(), n))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Testing
    for row in pascal_triangle():
        print(row, end='')
        if (input()):
            break
```

Answer (score 5):

**Names**

I am not fully convinced by the different function names but I have nothing better to suggest for the time being.

**Style**

Python has a [Style Guide called PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is an interesting read. The most significant impact for your code would be to use 4 spaces for each indentation level instead of 2.

**Simplify `double_chunker`**

In `double_chunker`, the following condition is never true:

```
elif i == leng:
  yield [lst[-1]]
```

Also, you don't need to handle explicitly the case:

```
elif i == 1:
  yield [lst[0], lst[1]]
```

as it is just a particular case for `[lst[i-1], lst[i]]` with `i == 1`.

**Simplify `chunk_adder`**

In `chunk_adder`, instead of:

```
if len(i) == 1:
  yield i[0]
else:
  yield sum(i)
```

We can write:

```
yield sum(i)
```

Then, we could rewrite the function using generator expressions:

```
def chunk_adder(lst):
  return (sum(i) for i in lst)
```

Then, it looks like the function is not really needed. We could write:

```
def pascal_next(lst):
  return [sum(i) for i in double_chunker(lst)]
```

---

At this stage, we have:

```
def double_chunker(lst):
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i == 0:
      yield [lst[0]]
    else:
      yield [lst[i-1], lst[i]]
  yield [lst[-1]]


def pascal_next(lst):
  return [sum(i) for i in double_chunker(lst)]

def pascal_triangle(rows):
  end = [[1]]
  for i in range(rows):
    end.append(pascal_next(end[-1]))
  return end


print(pascal_triangle(8))
```

**More simplification in `double_chunker`**

We could handle the case `i == 0` before the loop rather than inside the loop. That could lead to a slightly different behavior when the input is an empty list but that case is not handled properly anyway (exception thrown).

```
def double_chunker(lst):
  yield [lst[0]]
  for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    yield [lst[i-1], lst[i]]
  yield [lst[-1]]
```

Then, it becomes obvious what we want to do: we want to [iterate over all pairs of consecutive items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303224/iterate-over-all-pairs-of-consecutive-items-in-a-list) which is a problem common enough to find various solutions to it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any better code practices I should be employing and am not?

- The first thing that caught my attention is the missing tests

You should implement a few test cases to ensure that after changes the program does still work as intended

Both the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module or [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) are good Python modules for testing, I have used the `unittest` as an example

```
class PascalTriangleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_triangle_0(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            pascal_triangle(0), 
            [[1]]
        )

    def test_triangle_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            pascal_triangle(1), 
            [[1], [1, 1]]
        )

    def test_triangle_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            pascal_triangle(2), 
            [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
        )

    def test_triangle_3(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            pascal_triangle(3), 
            [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1]]
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

- The second one would be the missing docstrings

The comments below your code would be a good start to make the docstring for each function.

See [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), for docstring conventions

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything in my program that seems redundant, repetitive, or can be shortened?

The 22 lines of `double_chunker`, `chunk_adder`, and `pascal_next` can be shortened to

```
def pascal_next(lst):
  return [left + right for (left, right) in zip(lst + [0], [0] + lst)]
```

Comment: Or `return [sum(pair) for pair in zip(lst + [0], [0] + lst)]` to make use of the built in `sum`

Comment: @Ludisposed, I deliberately chose not to do that because I regard it as a pessimisation.

Comment: You could also omit the parenthesis: `[left + right for left, right in zip(lst + [0], [0] + lst)]`.